# Bootstrap carousel with table data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show my table with the slider but its showing in a single line or else the whole data is showing in one slider but I want to show 10,10 records in a single slider.

This is what I have tried but it's now working.

```
<uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
  <uib-slide ng-repeat="user in test" active="active" index="$index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>
                  <center>Address</center>
                </th>
                <th>Person</th>
                <th>Number</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td ng-click="gotoEdit(user) " class="curPointer "><a><u>{{user.Name}}</u></a></td>
                <td>{{ user.address.addressLine1}},{{user.address.city}},{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.Person}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.Phone}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

Comment: Create a code pen or plunker and state what you are trying to acheive!

Comment: You forgot to mention that you're using `angular-ui` directives. Here is a working code snippet example: https://plnkr.co/edit/baIwOWgUqu0Ti4eeltye?p=preview

Comment: Without seeing your js code it's hard to understand what's wrong. Check with more simple example (replace table with just h1 tags for example), also make sure that you have `active` variable in your scope